# Forms Authentication cookie is not working after FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie is called

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have forms authentication setup through a Web API project. The forms auth works fine to login the user to the web site (note: API server is not the same server as web server). However, the API services I have restricted to logged in users are returning a 401, because Request.IsAuthenticated = false when I send back the very same forms auth cookie the API server just set, back to itself.

I have no idea why this is happening. I verified the .ASPXAUTH cookie is being sent with the request. Forms Auth is setup consistently across API and Website; and the website picks up the forms auth cookie just fine. Why is my API server not recognizing my user as logged in, even though the API server itself set the cookie?

Comment: Not the same server but are the same machine keys configured? If not, the cookie issues by one server is not decrypted by the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The issue was a browser conflict with one of my Chrome add-ons. Once I opened the site up in a incognito window sans add-ons, it worked as expected.